# How can i fix my vs code intellisense lagging with mongoose package

Tags: mongoose, visual-studio-code, node-modules, intellisense

Whenever I create a schema The intel lisense works slowly and if I require it in other files the whole project intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

My VSCode smart tips is laggy! When I delete `node_modues` dir , everything is ok, so I started to check every package.

I tested lots of npm packages, and I found that is because Mongoose 6.x versions makes VSCode lag;

Then, I tester lower versions Mongoose, and the problem remains.

The reason is, when you use:

```
npm i mongoose@5.10.1
```

the `mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2` package will install Mongoose 6.0.10 version automatically because the required relation is :

`mongoose@5.10.11 › mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2 › mongoose@6.0.10`

but, I still don't know why 6.0.10 makes the IDE lag.